BizTalk Health Monitor V5 doesn't send e-mail on a schedule or when critical warning is detected
I'm trying to monitor my BizTalk Server 2020 with BHM V5.0.9118. I created a "Monitoring profile" and setted it like the following picture:

The Mail Settings window:

I have 2 send ports that are stopped:

When I launch a manual analyze or I hit "Test" button on "Mail" window I receive an e-mail but not with the schedule or when a critical warnings is detected, I receive nothing.
Can you help please?

Has it created a scheduled task in Task Scheduler that is enabled?   Does the user that it is running under have the right permissions to run?

Yes the task has been created, the user have the right permissions and the task is running successfully every 10 minutes regarding the "Last Run Result" on Task Scheduler.

@Dijkgraaf Any other idea please ?
